# Direct3D Window->Bounds.Width/Height differs from real resolution

Tags: visual-c++, directx-11

I noticed a strange behaviour with Direct3D while doing [this tutorial](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=112-4-5).

The dimensions I am getting from the Window Object differ from the configured resolution of windows. There I set 1920*1080, the width and height from the Winows Object is 1371*771.

```
CoreWindow^ Window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
// set the viewport
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport = { 0 };

viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
viewport.Width = Window->Bounds.Width; //should be 1920, actually is 1371
viewport.Height = Window->Bounds.Height;  //should be 1080, actually is 771
```

I am developing on an Alienware 14, maybe this causes this problem, but I could not find any answers, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreWindow sizes, pointer locations, etc. are *not* expressed in pixels. They are expressed in *Device Independent Pixels (DIPS)*. To convert to/from pixels you need to use the Dots Per Inch (DPI) value.

```
inline int ConvertDipsToPixels(float dips) const
{
    return int(dips * m_DPI / 96.f + 0.5f);
}

inline float ConvertPixelsToDips(int pixels) const
{
    return (float(pixels) * 96.f / m_DPI);
}
```

> `m_DPI` comes from `DisplayInformation::GetForCurrentView()->LogicalDpi` and you get the `DpiChanged` event when and if it changes.

See [DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173.aspx) for more details.

You should take a look at the Direct3D UWP Game templates on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates), and check out how this is handled in `Main.cpp`.

Comment: thanks for that information about the dpi! I didnt stumbled over that, yet. btw: the code in your repo seems very helpful to me, the coding style is very similar to that I learned till now. so, thanks for that, too :)